# Current required number of arguments for unfolding by `simpl`

Tags: coq

The [Coq Reference Manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.simpl) details how to use the `Arguments` directive with a `/` to mark a constant to be unfolded by the `simpl` tactic only if enough arguments are supplied.

Is there a way to see how many arguments arguments a constant currently requires to be unfolded?

Similarly, is there a way to see if a constant was flagged to never be simplified by `simpl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `About` vernacular gives this information (and other useful things):

```
Definition foo (n:nat) := n.
Arguments foo n/.
About foo.

Arguments foo/.
About foo.

Arguments foo : simpl never.
About foo.
```

Specifically the output includes "The reduction tactics unfold foo when applied to 1 argument", "...always unfold foo", and "never unfold foo".